# Software to automatically sync my Facebook events to Google Calendar

Tags: automation, facebook, google-calendar

I'm using Google Calendar for my time planning. I need to see all Facebook events I declared I'll attend, I'm interested in, or was invited. Manually copying events is tedious and prone to errors. Is there a software I could use to automatically update my google calendar, instantaneously or for example once a day, with events from Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any tool in theory:

1. Go to Facebook -> `Events` -> `Your events`.
2. Right click `Add to calendar` button on top right.
3. Copy URL.
4. Go to Google Calendar -> `Add calendar` -> `From URL`.
5. Paste the copied URL.

And that's it. External application may be nice for further filtering, but your choice if you trust it with your data.

Answer (score 0):

A friend recommended to me this online tool:

https://eventcal.flown.io/

So far, it seems to work correctly. It takes some time for it to sync up, but generally it synced all my events after one night of waiting.

I have no association with the tool or the author, and I don't think that friend who recommended it has any.

[image: Screenshot of the tool at the moment of posting]